# What could cause a flat loss function to suddenly decrease in a u-net used for denoising?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, loss-functions

So I am trying to understand [U-Nets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) better, and I built a very shallow U-Net  and trained it to denoise MNIST images (training set is 90% of the whole dataset).

The loss function evolution I obtained was very strange and I did not manage to understand it:
[image: Tensorboard screenshot of my loss function]

The loss I am using is mean square error and the x-axis is epochs.

My big problem with this loss function evolution is that if I had set for, say, 10 epochs, then I would have reached a wrong conclusion regarding this architecture.
So I guess my question is 2-folds:

- is there an explanation behind this weird loss function evolution?
- how to avoid early stopping in such situations (my validation loss follows exactly the same pattern)? Or even simply setting a number of epochs too low?

Note that this is a different problem than the one laid out in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300839/what-causes-a-sudden-drop-in-test-error-when-training-cnn), because in my case the loss function is absolutely flat.

---

EDIT

After reviewing my architecture, I noticed that my final activation was a ReLU instead of a sigmoid. With a sigmoid, I don't have this behaviour, but imho the question still stands.